# Why page speed insight shows wordpress admin bar

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed-insights, litespeed

While checking a url for page speed insight i am getting low score. The reason appears simple. The page speed insight is checking the page after logging in to the word-press dashboard.

The result mobile page screenshot shows wordpress admin bar on top.
[image]

I am using wordpress+Google Sitekit+Lightspeed Cache

Have cleared all transients

Still no go.

Comment: admin page shouldn't be cached. Do you have a test set URl that we can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

It shows the admin bar because you are logged in.

If you wish to force hide it, just include some custom code in your functions PHP to hide it when user X is logged in. This can be achieved with simple CSS.